# How can you set, if at all possible, the channels for OpenVDB export?

Tags: export

As we all know, the latest addition of OpenVDB in Blender is awesome and cool. Buuuut I still have some questions. When you export OpenVDB it's important to have the channels with them ( temperature, heat, density, velocity,...). Now, in Houdini you can set which channels you want to export with your OpenVDB files. In Blender it seems a little more random ( or I haven't found the settings panel yet ). When I cache a fire to OpenVDB I sometimes get just a density channel, sometimes density and temperature, sometimes nothing.

I don't have to tell you that these channels are super important, because they act as masks for shading ( at least, that is what I was told. ). So, in order to make this usable, and make me a very happy camper, I would like to know if it's possible at all to set these channels. Or at least where to find them. Or just let me know if this is a bug, and I'll report it.

Well, that's my predicament. I hope to find some answers.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

well, as far as I know there is just basic vdb support and blender does not offer you the possibilities houdini does. the vdb data is hard coded and depends on the sim settings. Though I have experienced that blender exported vdbs hold all the information needed to shade them within houdini. If you feel like the same simulation exports differently every time this is probably a bug. If it changes together with certain sim settings I would think it is supposed to be that way.